# How to store in server images upload by user with vue js and net core

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, file-upload, single-page-application

I'm currently working in a POS system and i'm writting the code in net core(web api) with vue as spa and mssql for my database.
I thought at first to use some storage service like aws-s3 or azure-storage ones to fetch the images from there, but I couldn't keep on going that way because there were extra costs, so I was requested to upload images to server better. So, now i'm having an issue and is that, the vue app has to be precompiled by babel when going to publish and therefore i can't changes the files in dist folder when running, so when i do it on dev stage (my machine) I see it working as good as possible, file uploads to folder ok and after compiling back, it will show the image. But, how do I accomplish this in prod stage?

Comment: This is the challenge of your SPA. Your `dist` is ephemeral and will be destroyed each time you deploy your app, so this is not a viable solution. Images should either be entirely served by your .net instance, and stored in a non-ephemeral folder, or you should use a technology like S3 with CloudFront. (which is going to be $0.03 per GB uploaded and $60 per 500k requests given a 500kb file)

Comment: Exactly what I said there, but as a Colombians and dollar being too high here, they got scared about possible costs. So, I thought about hosting them in server side, but I'm not totally sure how to, do you have any idea that may lights my way :)

Comment: You could try to use the iwebhostenvironment to upload images in the `wwwroot\Images` folder. Refer: [How to upload files (pdf & docs files) and display it in the view page](https://forums.asp.net/t/2159330.aspx?How+to+upload+files+pdf+docs+files+and+display+it+in+the+view+page). Besides, you could also consider storing the images into database (using byte array).